# replace android source package with modified package

Tags: android, package

is it possible to modify class SipProfile from android.net.sip package? What I only need is to fix one number (P-CSCF default port is 4060). I have found this source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/net/sip/SipProfile.java?av=f
but how to compile it and download all android 2.3.3 source codes - class files?
Or another tutorial in editing sources would be very appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to modify class SipProfile from android.net.sip package?

Only by creating your own firmware and installing it on whatever devices you want to have the modified behavior.

> how to compile it and download all android 2.3.3 source codes

Instructions for creating your own firmware can be found on http://source.android.com, such as the [Building the System](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) page.